# Install gcc 5 under ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gcc

I am trying to install gcc 5 under ubuntu 19.04, so I can compile some old code.  So far, I have only managed to install gcc 6, which does not fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @MMoallemi99 The unique answer to the above linked duplicate question does not work on 19.04 because gcc-5 is not included in the default  19.04 repositories.

Comment: I installed gcc-5, cpp-5, gcc-5-base, libgcc-5-dev, libasan2, and libmpx0. I was able to compile a sample hello_world.c program using gcc-5. However, I do not have the files under /usr/include/c++. Which package would give that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc-5 is not included in the default 19.04 repositories. The easiest way to circumvent this problem in Ubuntu 19.04 is to install gcc-4.8 instead. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
```

The hard way to solve this problem would be to download and install [gcc-5 from 18.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/gcc-5/download) in 19.04, but there are three dependencies of gcc-5 in 18.10 that would have to be downloaded and installed too, so try installing gcc-4.8 the easy way way first. The dependencies of gcc-5 in 18.10 are [cpp-5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/cpp-5/download), [gcc-5-base](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/gcc-5-base/download) and [libgcc-5-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libgcc-5-dev/download). These three dependencies of gcc-5 are also not available in the default Ubuntu 19.04 repositories.

If 18.10 is no longer supported, download and install [gcc-5 from 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-5/download), and there are three dependencies of gcc-5 in 18.04 that have to be downloaded and installed too. The dependencies of gcc-5 in 18.04 are [cpp-5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/cpp-5/download), [gcc-5-base](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-5-base/download) and [libgcc-5-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgcc-5-dev/download).

gcc packages in 18.04:
<sub>gcc-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb

cpp-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb

gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb

libgcc-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb</sub>

Change directories with `cd` to the directory the contains the 4 .deb files that you downloaded and run the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./cpp-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu8_amd64.deb ./gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu8_amd64.deb ./libgcc-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu8_amd64.deb ./gcc-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```

Comment: The dependencies of gcc-5 in 18.10 are cpp-5 gcc-5-base and libgcc-5-dev. These three dependencies of gcc-5 are also not available in the default Ubuntu 19.04 repositories.

Comment: Thanks for both idea, I tried sudo apt install gcc-4.8.  No luck there.  I will have to try to download and install gcc-5 and the 3 dependencies from 18.10.  Thanks.

Comment: I installed gcc-5, cpp-5, gcc-5-base, libgcc-5-dev, libasan2, and libmpx0.  I was able to compile a sample hello_world.c program using gcc-5.  However, I do not have the files under /usr/include/c++.  Which package would give that?  Thanks.

Comment: [libstdc++-5-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libstdc++-5-dev/download) - libstdc++-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu8_amd64.deb

Comment: Hot diggity!  Thank you.